# Adding a Next button to text inputs in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

I have an html table and in that table I have a column that contains text boxes. When I click start picking it will focus on the first text box and insert a "Next" button after it. When the user fills out the input and then hits next, I want it to hide that button and focus on the next input and insert a "Next" button after that one.

I would also like to add a Prev button to go back up the inputs and also if the user happens to focus on one of the other inputs, it will remove the next/prev buttons from the last focused input and add the next/prev button to the newly focused input.

Here is what I have tried so far:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/av9dx8kk/2/)

```js
function ScrollTo(Element_ID_or_Class) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(Element_ID_or_Class).offset().top - 120
  }, 1000);
}

//finish pick start
$(document).on('click', '#cancelpick', function() {
  $(this).attr('id', 'pick');
  $(this).removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success').html(' <i class="zmdi zmdi-case-play m-r-5"></i>Start Picking');;
  $('.Picking_TD').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).find('.txt_Picking_Vals').val();
    $(this).html(val);
  });
  $('.lblPicked').hide();
});
//finish pick end


//start picking start
var FocusedInput = '';
$(document).on('click', '#pick', function() {
  $(this).attr('id', 'cancelpick');
  $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger').html('<i class="zmdi zmdi-case-download m-r-5"></i>Finish Picking');
  var i = 0;
  $('.Picking_TD').each(function() {
    $(this).css('padding-top', '0').css('padding-bottom', '0');
    var DataID = $(this).data('id');
    var html = $(this).html();
    var input = $('<div class="fg-line">\
                                <input type="number" tabindex="' + i+++'" class="txt_Picking_Vals form-control fg-input" data-id="' + DataID + '" value="' + $.trim(html) + '" style="text-align:center; background-color:lightyellow;width:50px;"/>\
                            </div>\
                <br/><div class="lblPicked" style="font-size:10px; font-weight:300; position:relative; background-color:lightgreen;width:50px;">Picked</div>');

    $(this).html(input);
  });
  $('.lblPicked').hide();
  ScrollTo('.txt_Picking_Vals:first-child');
  $('.txt_Picking_Vals').first().after('<button id="next">next</button>');
  $('.txt_Picking_Vals').first().focus();
});
//End picking code


//next button code start
var obj = {
  index: 0
};

$(document).on('click', '#next', function() {
  $(this).remove();
  obj.index = $(".txt_Picking_Vals:focus").index();
  obj.index++;
  console.log(obj.index);
  $('.txt_Picking_Vals').eq(obj.index + 1).after('<button id="next">next</button>')
  $('.txt_Picking_Vals').eq(obj.index + 1).focus();
  obj.index = $(".txt_Picking_Vals:focus").index();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <table id="RMSI_Item_Table" class="table table-striped table-hover tablesaw tablesaw-stack" data-tablesaw-mode="stack" style="text-align:center;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Part Number</th>
        <th>Part Description</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>Picked</th>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="96">
        <td>1-4251</td>
        <td>RMSI 8ft Clik Clik 1 Button (Blue) Pole</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="96">0</td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="width:40px;">
          <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="96"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
            Edit
          </button>
        </td>
        <td style="width:40px;">
          <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="96"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="97">
        <td>1-4253</td>
        <td>RMSI Aluminum Pole Extension</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="97">0</td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="width:40px;">
          <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="97"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
            Edit
          </button>
        </td>
        <td style="width:40px;">
          <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="97"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="98">
        <td>1-4251</td>
        <td>RMSI 8ft Clik Clik 1 Button (Blue) Pole</td>
        <td>455</td>
        <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="98">0</td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="width:40px;">
          <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="98"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
            Edit
          </button>
        </td>
        <td style="width:40px;">
          <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="98"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="99">
        <td>17-3823</td>
        <td>Header Brackets - Universal Orientation (Starbucks)</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="99">0</td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="width:40px;">
          <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="99"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
            Edit
          </button>
        </td>
        <td style="width:40px;">
          <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="99"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="100">
        <td>3237-4222</td>
        <td>BLACKHAWK NETWORK Telecom FOS GPR Alaska Kit</td>
        <td>4545</td>
        <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="100">0</td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="width:40px;">
          <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="100"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
            Edit
          </button>
        </td>
        <td style="width:40px;">
          <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="100"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button id="pick" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-case-play m-r-5"></i>
  Start Picking</button>
<!-- Search panel end-->
```

Comment: it is no the problem @j08691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on you own code and guidelines I came up with this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#pick', function () {
    $('#pick').hide();
    $('#cancelpick').show();
    MakeRowsEditable();
    Focus($('.txt_Picking_Vals').first());
    obj.index = 0;
}).on('click', '#cancelpick, #done', function () {
    $('#cancelpick').hide();
    $('#pick').show();
    MakeRowsRegular();
}).on('click', '#next', function () {
    Focus($('.txt_Picking_Vals').eq(++obj.index));
}).on('click', '#prev', function () {
    Focus($('.txt_Picking_Vals').eq(--obj.index));
}).on('click', '.txt_Picking_Vals', function () {
    Focus($(this));
    obj.index = $(this).closest('.fg-line').data('tabindex');
});

var obj = {
    index: 0
};

function MakeRowsEditable() {
    var length = $('.Picking_TD').length;
    $('.Picking_TD').each(function (index) {
        var dataID = $(this).data('id');
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<div class="fg-line" data-tabindex="' + index + '">\
<input type="number" class="txt_Picking_Vals form-control fg-input" data-id="' + dataID + '" value="' + $.trim(text) + '" style="text-align:center; background-color:lightyellow;width:50px;"/>\
</div>\
<div class="pickNav ' + index + '" style="display:none;">' + (index != 0 ? '<button id="prev">prev</button>' : '') + (index != (length - 1) ? '<button id="next">next</button>' : '<button id="done">done</button>') + '<div>\
<br/><div class="lblPicked" style="display:none;font-size:10px; font-weight:300; position:relative; background-color:lightgreen;width:50px;">Picked</div>');
});
}

function MakeRowsRegular() {
    $('.Picking_TD').each(function () {
        var val = $(this).find('.txt_Picking_Vals').val();
        $(this).html(val);
    });
}

function Focus(el) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: el.offset().top - 120
    }, 1000);
    $('.pickNav:visible').hide();
    $('.pickNav.' + el.focus().closest('.fg-line').data('tabindex')).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
    <table id="RMSI_Item_Table" class="table table-striped table-hover tablesaw tablesaw-stack" data-tablesaw-mode="stack" style="text-align:center;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Part Number</th>
                <th>Part Description</th>
                <th>QTY</th>
                <th>Picked</th>
                <th>Section</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="96">
                <td>1-4251</td>
                <td>RMSI 8ft Clik Clik 1 Button (Blue) Pole</td>
                <td>34</td>
                <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="96">0</td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="96"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="96"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="97">
                <td>1-4253</td>
                <td>RMSI Aluminum Pole Extension</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="97">0</td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="97"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="97"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="98">
                <td>1-4251</td>
                <td>RMSI 8ft Clik Clik 1 Button (Blue) Pole</td>
                <td>455</td>
                <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="98">0</td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="98"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="98"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="99">
                <td>17-3823</td>
                <td>Header Brackets - Universal Orientation (Starbucks)</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="99">0</td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="99"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="99"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="100">
                <td>3237-4222</td>
                <td>BLACKHAWK NETWORK Telecom FOS GPR Alaska Kit</td>
                <td>4545</td>
                <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="100">0</td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="100"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="100"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<button id="pick" class="btn btn-success"><i class="zmdi zmdi-case-play m-r-5"></i>
Start Picking</button>
<button id="cancelpick" class="btn btn-danger" style="display: none;"><i class="zmdi zmdi-case-download m-r-5"></i>Finish Picking</button>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NeoSelcev/syoq56qu/4/)

I had changed your code a bit (JS mostly)... Do you want me to explain what and why was changed?

*** As for me this still isn't a best solution, as I'm not a big fan of jQuery (at least for such a simple tasks).

Comment: There is a bug in your code. If you pick and go through the inputs and hit finish picking. Once you start picking again it does not work.

Comment: Thanks. While looking at your code, how do you make the buttons visible? I need to move the buttons outside the fg-line div. That is for my input. Can you please do that? Also I wanted to add a done button on the last input.

Comment: @Hanoncs Hi, I've edited the answer. Now you have a finish button, and moved the navigation buttons,as you asked (actually you can move them wherever you like, so it wan't break).

Answer (score 2):

I have check the good `id` element and i add prev button. You removed element too early.

Please try:

```js
function ScrollTo(Element_ID_or_Class) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(Element_ID_or_Class).offset().top - 120
    }, 1000);
}

//finish pick start
$(document).on('click', '#cancelpick', function () {
    $(this).attr('id', 'pick');
    $(this).removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success').html(' <i class="zmdi zmdi-case-play m-r-5"></i>Start Picking');;
    $('.Picking_TD').each(function () {
        var val = $(this).find('.txt_Picking_Vals').val();
        $(this).html(val);
    });
    $('.lblPicked').hide();
});
//finish pick end


//start picking start
var FocusedInput = '';
$(document).on('click', '#pick', function () {
    $(this).attr('id', 'cancelpick');
    $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger').html('<i class="zmdi zmdi-case-download m-r-5"></i>Finish Picking');
    var i = 0;
    $('.Picking_TD').each(function () {
        $(this).css('padding-top', '0').css('padding-bottom', '0');
        var DataID = $(this).data('id');
        var html = $(this).html();
        var input = $('<div class="fg-line">\
                                <input type="number" tabindex="' + i+++'" class="txt_Picking_Vals form-control fg-input" data-id="' + DataID + '" value="' + $.trim(html) + '" style="text-align:center; background-color:lightyellow;width:50px;"/>\
                            </div>\
                <br/><div class="lblPicked" style="font-size:10px; font-weight:300; position:relative; background-color:lightgreen;width:50px;">Picked</div>');

        $(this).html(input);
    });
    $('.lblPicked').hide();
    ScrollTo('.txt_Picking_Vals:first-child');
    $('.txt_Picking_Vals').first().after('<span class="menuButton"><button id="prev">prev</button><button id="next">next</button></span>');
    $('.txt_Picking_Vals').first().focus();
});
//End picking code


//next button code start
var obj = {
    index: 0
};

$(document).on('click', '#next', function () {
   
 obj.index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    console.log(obj.index);
     $(".menuButton").remove();
    $('.txt_Picking_Vals').eq(obj.index + 1).after('<span class="menuButton"><button id="prev">prev</button><button id="next">next</button></span>')
    $('.txt_Picking_Vals').eq(obj.index + 1).focus();
    obj.index = $(".txt_Picking_Vals:focus").index();
});
$(document).on('click', '#prev', function () {
   
 obj.index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    console.log(obj.index);
     $(".menuButton").remove();
    $('.txt_Picking_Vals').eq(obj.index - 1).after('<span class="menuButton"><button id="prev">prev</button><button id="next">next</button></span>')
    $('.txt_Picking_Vals').eq(obj.index - 1).focus();
    obj.index = $(".txt_Picking_Vals:focus").index();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
    <table id="RMSI_Item_Table" class="table table-striped table-hover tablesaw tablesaw-stack" data-tablesaw-mode="stack" style="text-align:center;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Part Number</th>
                <th>Part Description</th>
                <th>QTY</th>
                <th>Picked</th>
                <th>Section</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="96">
                <td>1-4251</td>
                <td>RMSI 8ft Clik Clik 1 Button (Blue) Pole</td>
                <td>34</td>
                <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="96">0</td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="96"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="96"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="97">
                <td>1-4253</td>
                <td>RMSI Aluminum Pole Extension</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="97">0</td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="97"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="97"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="98">
                <td>1-4251</td>
                <td>RMSI 8ft Clik Clik 1 Button (Blue) Pole</td>
                <td>455</td>
                <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="98">0</td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="98"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="98"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="99">
                <td>17-3823</td>
                <td>Header Brackets - Universal Orientation (Starbucks)</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="99">0</td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="99"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="99"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="100">
                <td>3237-4222</td>
                <td>BLACKHAWK NETWORK Telecom FOS GPR Alaska Kit</td>
                <td>4545</td>
                <td class="Picking_TD" data-id="100">0</td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_Row_Edit" data-id="100"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-5"></i>
Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:40px;">
                    <button id="singlebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_Row_Delete" data-id="100"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete m-r-5"></i>
Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button id="pick" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-case-play m-r-5"></i>
Start Picking</button>
```

Comment: You need to put your code in your answer, not just in a link to a fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

In this snippet you can find a function that implements next, prev, done and restart buttons.

The function `nextOne()` does all the tricks

- If first row it shows only next button
- If last row it shows done, previous and restart button
- If first < row < last it shows next and previous button.

Other features that can be added is, for example, a "skip row" that checks if next/previous input is populated.

Also, when on last row, the "done" button can become always a new "next button" that points to the first input with no value and the restart value can reset also all the inputs.

These controls can be inserted in the buttons `click()` events.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function nextOne(row, nextButton, prevButton) {
    if(nextButton !== undefined) {
      $(nextButton).remove();
      $('.restart-button').remove();
    }
    
    if(prevButton !== undefined) {
      $(prevButton).remove();
    }
     
    var input = $(row).find('.pick-input').prop('disabled', false).focus();
    
    var column = $(row).find('.pick-input').parent();
    
    var prevButton = undefined;
    if(!$(row).is(":first-child")) {
      prevButton = $('<button/>', {class: 'prev-button', html: 'prev'});
       
      $(prevButton).click(function() {
        $(input).prop('disabled', true);
        var prevRow = $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr');
          
        nextOne(prevRow, nextButton, this);
      });
    }
        
    if($(row).is(":last-child")) {
      var nextButton = $('<button/>', {class: 'next-button', html: 'done'});
      var restartButton = $('<button/>', {class: 'restart-button', html: 'restart'});       
        
      $(restartButton).click(function() {
        $(input).prop('disabled', true);
        var row = $('.pick-table tbody tr:first');
        nextOne(row, nextButton, prevButton);  
      });
     
      $(column).append(restartButton);
    } else {
      var nextButton = $('<button/>', {class: 'next-button', html: 'next'});
    }
       
    $(nextButton).click(function() {
      $(input).prop('disabled', true);
      var nextRow = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');
          
      nextOne(nextRow, this, prevButton);
    });
        
    $(column).append(nextButton);
        
    $(column).append(prevButton);
  }
      
      
  $('#start').click(function() {
    var row = $('.pick-table tbody tr:first');
    nextOne(row);    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="pick-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>blabla</td>
      <td>other blablabla</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pick-input" step="1" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type=button>Edit</button>
        <button type=button>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>blabla</td>
      <td>other blablabla</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pick-input" step="1" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type=button>Edit</button>
        <button type=button>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>blabla</td>
      <td>other blablabla</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pick-input" step="1" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type=button>Edit</button>
        <button type=button>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>blabla</td>
      <td>other blablabla</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pick-input" step="1" disabled />
      </td>
     <td>
       <button type=button>Edit</button>
       <button type=button>Delete</button>
     </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="start" type="button">Start picking</button>
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but using html elements as selectors really kills your code. now I need to convert all the different selectors back to unique ones. Thank you for the answer though i really appreciate it.